# Finding side length of a cross-section of a pyramid frustum/truncated pyramid

Tags: math, 3d

How do I find the side length of a cross-section (as illustrated in
the drawing below - cross-section in
red) of a pyramid frustum/truncated pyramid?

[image]

I know the side-lengths of the top and bottom base, the height of the
frustum and the distance to the cross-section. Furthermore I know the
top and bottom base are parallel and that the center of the top and
bottom base are directly on top of each other.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The proportions are linear, so just interpolate the lengths of the bottom and top sides with the proportion of the cut height with the total height.

```
cut_side = (cut_height/total_height)*(bottom_side-top_side)+top_side
```

(Anyway, double check it to be 100% sure).

Comment: alternatively: alpha*top_side + (1-alpha)*bottom_side, where alpha = cut height / total height